# Create Django user by URL for django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to create a user through a url and not through Django admin site?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Only writing your own auth system. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system).